# why netty FastThreadLocal public final V get(InternalThreadLocalMap threadLocalMap) does not call registerCleaner method?

Tags: java, netty

Today I saw FastThreadLocal.

```
public final V get() {

    InternalThreadLocalMap threadLocalMap = InternalThreadLocalMap.get();

    Object v = threadLocalMap.indexedVariable(index);

    if (v != InternalThreadLocalMap.UNSET) {
        return (V) v;
    }

    V value = initialize(threadLocalMap);
    registerCleaner(threadLocalMap);
    return value;
}

public final V get(InternalThreadLocalMap threadLocalMap) {
    Object v = threadLocalMap.indexedVariable(index);
    if (v != InternalThreadLocalMap.UNSET) {
        return (V) v;
    }

    return initialize(threadLocalMap);
}
```

Why does `public final V get()` method call `registerCleaner(threadLocalMap)` method, but `public final V get(InternalThreadLocalMap threadLocalMap)` does not?

Comment: Its really hard to guess the opinion and reason of other developers

Comment: if public final V get(InternalThreadLocalMap threadLocalMap) method does not call registerCleaner(threadLocalMap), could possible memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

`registerCleaner` was removed all together in the last releases. It is not needed anymore at all.